# does loading style from another folder effect on better main page loading?

Tags: css, loading

I was wondering if I load Style from another folder instead of root does it effect on better web loading or not?!for example i load style.css from css folder

Comment: Consider adding “css” tag to put your question into proper context, and also removing “styles” tag which is not recommended for use as being too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes absolutely no difference.

Better, would be to combine and minify your CSS files, loading them from a single file. The fewer requests your application makes back to the server to load a file (from wherever path) the better.

Comment: many css comes from plugins how can i suppose to merge them together?!

Comment: you may not be able to merge them all, just merge the ones you can control. Fewer the better.

Comment: i have one style.css that loading from root and two bootstrap css file that loading from cdn address https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css
what dou you think about these?

Comment: that's fine... this sounds like too much upfront optimisation. Unless your site is receiving millions of hits/hour this isn't going to be a problem, even then, other things will cause more issues

Comment: my website is auto smrat feeds and fetch many items in hour and this effects on loading!! http://akhbartop.ir/